# Migrating JDK8 to JDK11 causes compilation error "package javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters does not exist"

Tags: java, jaxb, java-11

We are migrating our application from JDK8 to JDK11 so as in JDK11 they have removed javax.xml.bind package so i have added separate dependency like jaxb-api and jaxb-runtime for this.

But still I am facing this compilation error

> package javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters does not exist

Note:- Changed my java version for project to 11 and set java version for tomcat also to 11.

I am facing this issue while we are converting xsd into a jar so xsd is successfully converted into java classes but when we try to compile this java classes by using JavaCompiler so we got this error **package javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters does not exist** as our java classes are using some annotation from this package.

I checked jaxb-api jar is present into m2 repo and WEB-INF/lib also so can someone can help me to find rootcause and solution for this issue.

I have added seperate dependency for JAXB-API but still not working and i have also tried to add this jaxb-api jar manually in build path but that also not worked.